# How do I mirror nuget packages only from a specified owner?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

I would like to mirror packages from nuget.com, but not the entire repository, and filtering by owner would be my preferred method. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I mirror nuget packages only from a specified owner?

I am afraid there is no such option or setting to mirror packages from nuget.com only from a specified owner directly.

But you could filter by a search term to a specific property by using the syntax `<property>:<term>` where `<property>` (case-insensitive) can be `id`, `packageid`, `version`, `title`, `tags`, `author`, `description`, `summary`, and `owner`.

For example, if we want to get the nuget packages only from the owner jamesnk(The owner of `Newtonsoft.Json`), we could filtering it by `Owner:jamesnk` on `nuget.org`, from the NuGet CLI, and within the NuGet Package Manager UI in Visual Studio:

[image]

See [Search Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/finding-and-choosing-packages#search-syntax) for some more details.

Besides, if you want a repository for those packages from specified owner, you can download those packages and set them into the local feed: [Local feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds).